# Add list of values to every single entry in a cloumn

Tags: r

I would like to add a list of company names to every date in a column.

My DF has a column with several hundred dates.

```
Date
01.01.2014
02.01.2014
03.01.2014
01.02.2014
```

And I have a list of several hundred companies, eg Hall, Mull, Hen, etc

I would like to have in the end a data frame that looks like that:

```
Date         Company
01.01.2014   Hall
01.01.2014   Mull
01.01.2014   Hen
02.01.2014   Hall  
02.01.2014   Mull
02.01.2014   Hen
03.01.2014   Hall
03.01.2014   Mull
03.01.2014   Hen
01.02.2014   Hall
01.02.2014   Mull
01.02.2014   Hen
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(Date=Date, Company=Company)
```

Answer (score 0):

this sould do it:

```
head(DF)

> Date
  01.01.2014
  02.01.2014
  03.01.2014
  01.02.2014

DF[,"Company"] <- companylist
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is expand grid:

```
#input
companies<-c("Hall", "Mull", "Hen")
date<-c("01.01.2014", "02.01.2014", "03.01.2014", "01.02.2014")

#Make complete grid
output<-expand.grid(date, companies)
#rename columns
names(output)<-c("Date", "Company")
#place in desired order
output<-output[order(output$Date),]
```